# Wildcard search in Exchange Online PowerShell cmdlets

Tags: windows, powershell, exchange, microsoft-office-365

Are wildcards supported in Exchange Online PowerShell cmdlets? I want to create a new Address List which filters by Mail address but cannot get it to work.

The following command yields no results even though there are users with such a mail address:

```
Get-Recipient -Filter {(Alias -ne $null) -and (PrimarySmtpAddress -like '*@domain.com')}
```

When I type in the whole mail address by hand it returns a result, so it is clear that the wildcard filter does not work.

So are wildcards not supported? If that is the case, then why does the following command return results when filtering mail contacts?

```
Get-Recipient -Filter {(Alias- ne $null) -and (ExternalEmailAddress -like '*@domain.com')}
```

Comment: Your post is missing the closing brace (aka curly bracket). Did you have that when you ran the command? This exact syntax worked for me when I ran it in my environment using my domain name.

Comment: Hi, it's been a long time, is there any update? If the below answers are helpful to you, you could mark the best answer. Have a nice day:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem that you may be running into is that some attributes are not usable with the -Filter parameter of the `Get-Recipient` command. For example:

> `Get-Mailbox -Filter {(Alias -ne $null) -and (ExternalEmailAddress -like '*@example.com')}`

Results in:

> Cannot bind parameter 'Filter' to the target. Exception setting "Filter":
> ""ExternalEmailAddress" is not a recognized filterable property. For a
> complete list of filterable properties see the command help.

One way you can get around this takes longer to process, but works: get all recipients that have an alias, and then use the `Where` function to process the 2nd part of your query. The resulting command set would look like this:

`(Get-Recipient -Filter {(Alias -ne $null)} -ResultSize Unlimited).Where{$_.EmailAddresses -like "*example.com"}`

Using the above `Where` method gives you the same results as piping to the `Where-Object` cmdlet, but is faster. The following syntax will provide the same results:

`Get-Recipient -Filter {(Alias -ne $null)} -ResultSize Unlimited | Where-Object {$_.EmailAddresses -like "*example.com"}`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the official documentation **[Filterable properties for the Filter parameter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/filter-properties?view=exchange-ps#filterable-properties)**, the cmdlet `-Filter` should support wildcard character.

I tried to run commands with this cmdlet, then I found `username*` is allowed, but `*domain.com` isn't allowed.), it looks like the `-RecipientFilter` cmdlet(**[In cloud-based environments, you can't use a wildcard as the first character. For example, 'Sales*' is allowed, but '*Sales' isn't allowed.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/Set-DynamicDistributionGroup?view=exchange-ps)**).

To get the recipient email addresses, you could try to run the following commands:

```
Get-Recipient | where{($_.Alias -ne $null) -and ($_.PrimarySmtpAddress -like '*@domain.com')}
```

Or:

```
Get-Recipient -Filter {(Alias -ne $null) -and (EmailAddresses -like '*@domain.com')}
```